# Differentiate between uses of Adapter and Listener?

Tags: android, listener, actionlistener, ontouchlistener, android-adapterview

Working with Android from begging it's hard to differentiate in term Adapter and Listener and it's uses. I know the role of Adapter and Adapter View but is Listener can perform the same task as Adapter. Confusing a bit more.I request please give a simple explanation to understanding it.

Comment: `Listener can perform the same task as Adapter` ... and who told you so?

Comment: But can we use both in same method as you suggested they perform same task @BernoulliGate

Comment: I didn't suggest anything, I reported your (wrong!) words. And they don't perform the same task.

Comment: Dear Bernoulli if I know that Listener perform different task, not perform same task as Adapter why I ask here. I write wrong words which you reported, I accept. As a beginner it's happen that's why here to ask other. But okay, thank for your report. @BernoulliGate

Comment: Well I expressed myself poorly. I didn't mean "report" in that sense. I meant "copied into my comment".

Answer (score 0):

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

An adapter is just a bridge between your view and an android component. For example, a recyclerViewAdapter "adapts" your view to the recycler adapter.

In the other hand, a listener is a pattern for creating asynchronous callbacks. For example, `onClickListener` trigger an event every time that the user performs a click on that view.

Comment: Thanks cherif. But one more regarding these two term Adapter and Listener i.e. when we use both in same method we first use Adapter to provide view or data then we may use the onClickListener or other Listener to trigger that event. That's true, I am right to understand your suggestion here. @cherif

Comment: Thanks a lot @cherif